# How to show audio routing action sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I'm trying to achieve the action sheet like how it is in the native Voicemail. When connected to a bluetooth headset, the "Speaker" button will turn into "Audio". Selecting the "Audio" button will show an action sheet to select an audio output. Something similar can be done with `MPVolumeView.showsRouteButton`, but that is not what I'm going after. How can I achieve this action sheet style? [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your own routing sheet you can grab all available devices and switch between them. This [blog](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2016/06/select-device-or-bluetooth-audio-output.html) should be helpful

I do not believe AVAudioSession can return the list of devices though. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643516/list-available-output-audio-target-avaudiosession) seems to have a few hacky ways to do so.